# Set selected option JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jquery-1.12.3.min.js and dynamically get options for select

```
function loadCompanies() {
if ($("#isSubsidiaryCompany").is(":checked")) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "get_companies",
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                $('#companiesList').append($('<option>', {
                    value : data.id,
                    text : data.name
                }));
            });
        }

    })
    $("#companiesSelect").show();
    $('#companiesList').val(data.id);
} else {
    $("#companiesSelect").hide();
}
```

I want to set option selected but `$('#companiesList').val(data.id)` doesn`t work, could you suggest me the right way do achieve this, thanks in advance

Comment: Does your options gets dynamically generated well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the value outside of the AJAX callback function. Which means that those options are not guaranteed that they will be there. Put your code into the success callback:

```
if ($("#isSubsidiaryCompany").is(":checked")) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "get_companies",
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                $('#companiesList').append($('<option>', {
                    value : data.id,
                    text : data.name
                }));
            });
            $("#companiesSelect").show();               // < === HERE ===
            $('#companiesList').val(data.id);
        }

    })
// ...
```

Also, to which `data` are you referring to in your `.val(data.id)`?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the problem is in data variable, i didn`t notice it

Answer (score 0):

$('#companiesList').val(data.id)

I think there is problem with your data object. please make sure that data.id shoudl contain something.